# Oracle: Analyze table vs Gather_Table_Stats vs Gather_Schema_Stats

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

Currently in my DB, my predecessor who was working on DB has created a job which on every weekend gathers a list of all tables in the DB and individually for every table executes below two commands in that order:

```
ANALYZE TABLE xxTable_Namexx ESTIMATE STATISTICS FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE 75 SAMPLE 100 PERCENT;

EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(xxSchemaxx,xxTable_Namexx,cascade=>TRUE);
```

**Recently someone suggested to me that:**

1.) ANALYZE table is an old method of gathering stats and the optimizer doesn't use it anymore? is it true that the stats from this command is useless throughout the DB or is it being used somewhere?

2.) Instead of doing all this, it is enough to daily run:

```
dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(xxSchemaxx,cascade=>true);
```

What is the size/sample % if nothing is specified ??

3.) What is the general practice/frequency for gather stats in a database. (Data is being updated,inserted,deleted on a daily basis). I still prefer doing it every week-end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/general.htm#ADMIN11525 and https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#ARPLS059

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the link. It was very helpful & enlightening!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [ANALYZE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4005.htm#SQLRF01105) is hardly used nowadays:

> For the collection of most statistics, use the DBMS_STATS package,
>   which lets you collect statistics in parallel, collect global
>   statistics for partitioned objects, and fine tune your statistics
>   collection in other ways. See [Oracle Database PL/SQL Packages and
>   Types Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#ARPLS059) for more information on the DBMS_STATS package.
>
> Use the ANALYZE statement (rather than DBMS_STATS) for statistics
>   collection not related to the cost-based optimizer:
>
> - To use the `VALIDATE` or `LIST CHAINED ROWS` clauses
> - To collect information on freelist blocks

What is the size/sample % if nothing is specified ??

Parameter is called [estimate_percent](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#sthref10621):

> Percentage of rows to estimate (`NULL` means compute): The valid range
>   is [0.000001,100]. Use the constant `DBMS_STATS.AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE` to
>   have Oracle determine the appropriate sample size for good statistics.
>   This is the default.The default value can be changed using the
>   `SET_DATABASE_PREFS` Procedure, `SET_GLOBAL_PREFS` Procedure,
>   `SET_SCHEMA_PREFS` Procedure and `SET_TABLE_PREFS` Procedure.

Default value you can interrogate by function `DBMS_STATS.get_param('ESTIMATE_PERCENT')` or `DBMS_STATS.GET_PREFS('ESTIMATE_PERCENT')`

By default Oracle creates an internal scheduler job at installation which gathers the statistics automatically at night time. (called `BSLN_MAINTAIN_STATS_JOB`)

Comment: `Use the ANALYZE statement (rather than DBMS_STATS) for statistics collection not related to the cost-based optimizer:` So its still useful to collect some statistics ?? What are those statistics used for ? Thanks for the response.